# How do I get rid of password restrictions in passwd

Tags: linux, gentoo, passwd

My usual password just doesn't fit into its standards, and frankly this install doesn't need to be fort knox. Is there any way to disable them?

edit: this helped me https://www.reddit.com/r/Gentoo/comments/qf67k9/gentoo_very_big_password_requirements/

Answer (score 7):

Check `/etc/pam.d/passwd` and any other files `@include`d by it.

You should find a line that begins with the word `password` and mentions the PAM Unix-style password storage module: `pam_unix.so`. The options specified to it control which password hashing algorithm is used and which checks are applied when setting new passwords to `/etc/shadow`. Your distribution should include a man page for `pam_unix.so`, although the exact way to view it can vary a little - try `man pam_unix`, and if it does not work, `man pam_unix.so`. The `obscure` and `minlen=N` options might be the ones causing the system to reject some password candidates.

There may be other PAM modules participating in password quality checking, too: any PAM configuration line that begins with the word `password` specifies a module that participates in the password setting process. For example, there might be a `pam_passwdqc.so` or `pam_cracklib.so` module.

In addition, the legacy file `/etc/login.defs` might still contain some password-related settings, depending on the distribution.

**However:** if you choose to use simple passwords, **make sure your system does not contain any internet-accessible services that would use them for authentication!** Malware developers are clever, and often find non-obvious ways to abuse any services they can gain access to.

Comment: +1; An anecdote relevant to the security warning: I used a laptop for {one or two} weeks never connecting to the internet. Google Locations knows the exact GPS and timing after accessing `gmail` later.

Answer (score 6):

If you change your account's password as `root`, then the password restrictions are ignored (they become warnings, as root is trusted to know what they're doing). To do so, log in as your normal user and run `sudo passwd <yourusername>`, for example `sudo passwd wtry`.

You will be prompted for your existing password (to become root), and then your new password, twice. You will probably receive a warning that the password does not meet the preset restrictions, but they will be ignored.

Comment: This is so much simpler than other possible solutions, for the OP's use-case.  Just force the password to what you want by using sudo.